# How to plot chart in GraphView with no background?

Tags: android, background, android-graphview

How to make graphview background completely blank, not even show x axis and y axis.
couldn't find anything on web

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
I got my solution by adding these lines

mygraphview.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.NONE);// It will remove the background grids

 mygraphview.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsVisible(false);// remove horizontal x labels and line
  mygraphview.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsVisible(false);
// remove vertical labels and lines
```

Comment: In addition, you may have to set the background to invisible: mygraphview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);